# Installing HHVM on centos 6.5

Tags: centos, dependencies, hhvm

So I have followed about 8 tutorials on how to install hhvm on centos 6.5. However, I always fail when i do the `sudo yum install hhvm` portion with the following error:

```
Error: Package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
           Requires: mysql
Error: Package: gnote-0.6.3-3.el6.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: libboost_system-mt.so.5()(64bit)
           Removing: boost-system-1.41.0-27.el6.x86_64 (@base)
               libboost_system-mt.so.5()(64bit)
           Updated By: boost-system-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
               Not found
Error: Package: gnote-0.6.3-3.el6.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5()(64bit)
           Removing: boost-filesystem-1.41.0-27.el6.x86_64 (@base)
               libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5()(64bit)
           Updated By: boost-filesystem-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
               Not found
```

Now I am not a centos 6.5 pro admin so this may be very simple but I can't seem to find a way to clear up these dependency issues. Any ideas?

Comment: I do not want to run on your parade, however PHP people are claiming that with PHP 6, the differences on performance are minimal. as for the dependencies, have you forgotten to do a yum update recently?

Comment: Why would I update to php 6 when php 7 is around the corner? That said, I am on php 5.6 and am not going to put php 6 or 7 on either of them till they are more stable as this is an enterprise application. Therefore HHVM is my best option imo.

Comment: How about the yum update?

Comment: I apologize, I am currently backing up my VM to make sure i don't screw things up. I will let you know as soon as its done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me your dependencies are not up to date. Run an

```
sudo yum update
```

and after that your yum install should run without any problems.